# The extension of functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I'm facing the proof, using theorem of Hahn-Banach.

The **Theorem** is following:

In normed space every linear, continuous functional f on vector subspace $M \subset X$ can be extended to a continuous functional F on X with norm preserved: $\forall_{f \in M'} \exists_{F \in X'}: F|_{M}=f$ and $||F||=||f||$.

**Proof:**
Let us take $p(x):= ||f|| \cdot ||x||$ for every $x \in X$. Then:
$$ \forall_{x \in M} |f(x)| \leq ||f|| \cdot ||x|| = p(x)$$
Using theorem of Hahn-Banach there exists a functional $F$ extending $f$.
$$ ||F|| \geq ||f|| \text{ (because F extends f),}$$ 
$$ ||F|| = sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||Fx|| \leq sup_{||x|| \leq 1} p(x) = sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||f|| \cdot ||x|| = ||f|| $$
So $||F|| = ||f||$.

And there is my question. Why the $ sup_{||x|| \leq 1} ||Fx|| \leq sup_{||x|| \leq 1} p(x) $ ? And why $p(x)$ isn't in the norm? Should it be?

Regards

Comment: Hi Olga, as you can see, YuiTo Cheng and I added some tags to your question. In general it is recommanded to use not only a very narrow tag like "hahn-banach-theorem", but also some broader tags like "functional-analysis" to give your question more exposure. The mouseover of the tags shows you the number of watchers, which can give you an idea how many people will see your question when you add a specific tag.

Comment: One more comment regarding LaTeX: Use \| instead of || to get the spacing correct, use \sup instead of sup to get the right font, and enclose all formulas, even single letters, in $ signs.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $p(x)$ is a seminorm such that $|f(x)|\leq p(x)$, so using the Hahn-Banach theorem there is a linear functional $F$ extending $f$ such that for all $x\in X$ 
$$|F(x)|\leq p(x)=\|f\|\|x\|.$$
So 
$$\|F\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|F(x)|\leq\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}p(x)=\|f\|.$$

I'm not sure what you mean with $p(x)$ being in the norm, but it might be useful to note that $p(x)$ is real number, not an element of $x$.

Comment: It's an easy consequence from $\|\cdot\|$ being a norm. $p(x+y)=\|f\|\|x+y\|\leq \|f\|\|x\|+\|f\|\|y\|=p(x)+p(y)$ and $p(\alpha x)=\|f\|\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|f\|\|x\|=|\alpha|p(x)$. $p$ is even a norm if $f\neq0$.